# Can't Install Miniconda 3

Tags: python, software-installation, bash

Following these steps:

```
wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
```

I get to License Agreement and after I enter 'yes', I just get a series of 'y' repeating to infinity. Help?

```
y
y
y
y
y
y
y
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing.  It seems like the root cause of the problem is you need to run the installer with sudo (no pun intended).

```
sudo /bin/bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-armv7l.sh
```

I did that and it works just fine.  Odd though, I've never had to do that on any x86_64 install.

At any rate, this fixes the problem.  Also, if you invoke it with bash, you don't need to chmod it first.